# При появлении на экране браузера блока div (их несколько) вызывать ajax

Tags: jquery

Господа, приветствую.

Дано: на странице несколько блоков вида `<div id="idXXX"></div>`

Задача: при прокрутке страницы , если блок в видимой пользователю части экрана браузера - вызывать скрипт ajax  (помечать прочитанным)

Пытаюсь это решить с помощью jquery, не могу победить :( Буду рад помощи, заранее спасибо.

**В идеале еще бы так, чтобы второй раз не вызывалась одна и та же функция, т.е. чтобы срабатывало для каждого блока один раз**

Наброски:

```js
 function inWindow(s)
    {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var currentEls = $(s);
    var ids=s;
    var offset = currentEls.offset();
    if(scrollTop <= offset.top && (currentEls.height() + offset.top) < (scrollTop + windowHeight))
      {
      /*
      $.ajax({
           url:  "status.php?admin='.$admin.'&id=" + ids + ""  // не работает, не вставляет ids
          });
      */
      console.log("Блок "+ids+" в области видимости");
      }
    }

  $(document).scroll(function ()
    {
    inWindow("#id1")
    });
  $(document).scroll(function ()
    {
    inWindow("#id2")
    });
  $(document).scroll(function ()
    {
    inWindow("#id3")
    });
  $(document).scroll(function ()
    {
    inWindow("#id4")
    });
  $(document).scroll(function ()
    {
    inWindow("#id5")
    });
```

```css
.active
  {
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="active"></div>

<div id="id2" class="active"></div>

<div id="id3" class="active"></div>

<div id="id4" class="active"></div>

<div id="id5" class="active"></div>
```

Comment: А если их будет миллион, вы для каждого отдельно писать будете и плодить один и тот же слушатель?

Comment: Так вот я некоторые моменты не понимаю в jquery, поэтому и пишу о помощи. Знаю что тут косяк на косяке у меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объяснения в комментах к коду

```js
let of = $(window).height() / 2, // Отступ, в данным случае считает от центра экрана
    el = $('.active'), // Какие блоки учитывать
    cur = false; // Тут храним блок в скролле, чтобы срабатывало один раз

$(window).on('scroll', function() { // при скролле..
  let sY = $(this).scrollTop(); // получаем текущею позицию скролла
  el.each(function() { // проходим по ВСЕМ блокам которые нужно учитывать
    let el = $(this); // запоминаем его, чтобы не обращаться к нему
    
    // Тут проверяем, входил ли позиция скролла - отступ в границу блока.
    if(el.position().top - of <= sY
    && el.position().top + el.outerHeight() - of > sY) { // если да, то
      if(cur !== el.attr('id')) { // проверяем является ли этот блок тем, что был ранее в записи, если нет, то
        cur = el.attr('id'); // Сохраняем его (НЕ УДАЛЯТЬ)
        el.css('background', 'green'); // Для демо, мы показываем его зелёным
        console.info(el.attr('id')); // И выводим его ID в консоль.
        // Вместо кода выше, нужно оказать ваш AJAX запрос.
      }
    } else { // Если скролл не на границе
      if(cur === el.attr('id')) { // Проверим является ли он тем, что в записи
        el.css('background', ''); // удалим у него фон
        console.info('ушли с '+cur); // покажем что мы с него ушли
        // Тут может быть какое-то обратное действие, допустим снять класс с объекта который покинул область видимости.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 42px !important;} /* для демо */

.active {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="id1" class="active"></div>
<div id="id2" class="active"></div>
<div id="id3" class="active"></div>
<div id="id4" class="active"></div>
<div id="id5" class="active"></div>
```

Советую чтобы между блоками `.active` не было отступов вообще.

Comment: Если это решение вашей проблемы, то надо "отметить как решение"

Comment: Нужно время разобраться в коде, помечу как решение обязательно, спасибо большое. Скажите, пожалуйста, как  заставить выводить в код ids - значение этой ids ? $.ajax({
           url:  "status.php?admin='.$admin.'&id=" + ids + ""  // не работает, не вставляет ids
          });

Comment: @hibinyru, а что находится в `ids`?

Comment: @De.Minov, спасибо громаднейшее за код! все заработало. с предыдущим коментом разобрался. СПАСИБО!  через 5 часов смогу вам 50 зачислить!!!

Comment: @hibinyru, рад что помог.

Comment: @De.Minov, тут еще вопрос нарисовался. Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Экран монитора большой. Первый блок высотой, допустим 100px и он находится наверху экрана. Так как в коде "of = $(window).height() / 2" - середина экрана, то при скроле вниз верхний-первый блок остался "не прочитанным". есть какое то решение для этого?

Comment: @hibinyru, можно `offset` поставить 0, тогда "текущий" блок будет считаться от самого верха вьюпорта, но тогда может не учитываться нижний..

Comment: @De.Minov, а это значение в пикселях, процентах или какой-то другой величине?

Comment: @hibinyru, ну вообще в пикселях, только без указания `px`